# Change UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I want to ask if it is possible to change UITabBarController to another UITabBarController as you navigate through your app?

Like... I have 3 tabs, the one is a navigationcontroller. When I navigate through the tab with the UINavigationController, I will have 2 other tabs.

I just want to know if it's possible and a hint.

Thanks.

Comment: That's a pretty bad UI design IMO which defeats the purpose of a TabBar.

Comment: Thanks, at least I know I shouldn't do this then. :)

Comment: You may want to use a UISegmentedControl in the second view that comes in after navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by Bourne that's not a good idea, not easily possible (you'd have to remove the tabbarcontroller then create another and remove that and re-add the first one when you wanted to go back) plus it would confuse users and Apple likely wouldn't allow it in the app store.

It would be better to have a toolbar inside a tabbar.